# find/trace element in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, search

Let's say there is an array like `var arr = [{id:'anId', value: 'aValue'}, ......]` and a custom sorting by `value` is done to it:

```
arr.sort(function(){
   // sorting.....
});
```

Is there a way to trace an element during sorting?

If not is there an efficient search implementation of finding it by `id` without iterating and checking on each item?

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: unless you have the array sorted by id, no way of finding by id without iterating all. If you do have them sorted, a binary search approach would work, but doubt you need it to be that efficient, is your data big?

Comment: It might get big, yes. Unfortunately I need the order by `value` property because I'm more interested in the position than the element itself  or a simple map with `id` keys would help in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "trace"? Do you know where the element is before sorting, and want to keep track of where it ended up after sorting? Or do you want to look for the element (not yet knowing where it is) at the same time as you're sorting the array?

Comment: @Edward: Yes, I know its postion before sorting

Comment: how many times do you need to search by id after the sort?

Comment: OK, and are you implementing this "custom sorting function" yourself, or is it coming from a library you don't have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already applying a sorting method, which will iterate through all the elements, you can get the best performance by checking for your target ID during the sort iterations:

```
var prevPos = // here goes the current index of the object in the array
var item;
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.id == 'mySearchID'){
        console.log('found it, better store it')
        item = a;
        f(a.value < b.value) prevPos++ // item moved, change current pos
    }else if(b.id == 'mySearchID'){
         console.log('found it, better store it')
         item = b;
         if(a.value < b.value) prevPos-- // item moved, change current pos
    }
    //your sorting method
    return a.value < b.value
}); 
console.log(item, prevPos) //gets item obj and its new position in the array
```

Note that `item` may be updated multiple times depending on how many times your desired object is moved during the sort, but by the end of the sort `item` will be a reference to your object in the sorted array.

Comment: This good but I am interested in its position in the array not the object itself, because I know it before sorting and I can get it but it is the order I'm interested in. 
I wasn't very clear about that. Thank you for the kind help, appreciate it +1.

Comment: @kidwon Well, you can then just do arr.indexOf(item) to get new position. If you want to do it more efficently, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/jef4z96o/

Comment: I doubt that is reliable because one can't determine which elements are compared against each other, the elements are not shifted with 1. The shift step might be across `7` items for example. So `prevPos`  represents the overall shifting progress ascending or descending during the sort. http://jsfiddle.net/jef4z96o/1/ but not the current position of the element.

Comment: But `indexOf` is working I thought it works on primitive values only , 10x. You should put that in your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Although in js it isn't faster than a for loop so no progress here.

Comment: @kidwon not sure the prevPos always work, but in the fiddle you made if you set prevPos as 5 at the beggining it gives 0 at the end, which should be correct. And if its only one time search, indexOf shouldn´t be very slow. Could optimze it depending on your sorting method and the number of objects you have in the array, need more info

Comment: In my case it gives `-3`, in the fiddle I've posted.

Comment: @kidwon Yeah, because prevPos must begin with the current index of the object with the id of mySearchID, in your case its 5, not 2. So that gives a -3 difference

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed! My bad so I've changed the id only.
In this case you may update your answer I would gladly accept it.